# WordPress - Executing PHP in Theme Options Panel

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a theme options panel for a client however they would like the ability to enter PHP code in the textareas and have it executed on the front end.

However, when they enter the code, it does not display properly in the front end, please see the following two screenshots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm9Qv.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXeVO.png

It looks like the code is being stripped when displayed on the front end.  Its displayed using this code:

```
    <?php global $options;
foreach ($options as $value) {
    if (get_settings( $value['id'] ) === FALSE) { $$value['id'] = $value['std']; } else { $$value['id'] = get_settings( $value['id'] ); }
}
?>

<?php echo $ag_footer_top; ?>
```

How can I get it to work properly?  Is it possible?

If I enter the following into the theme options:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'first','fallback_cb'=> ” ) ); ?>
```

It gets saved INTO the database as:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( \'theme_location\' => \'first\',\'fallback_cb\'=> ” ) ); ?>
```

And its displayed on the front end as:

```
\'first\',\'fallback_cb\'=&gt; ” ) ); ?&gt;
```

Comment: you have to use html_decode and than pass the setting value into eval

Comment: How is it being saved in your database?

Comment: I edited my main post with code examples of what I enter, and how it is saved into the database

Comment: please show us real output instead of dom tree view, and php code for $ag_footer_top var

Comment: I provided 3 examples at the bottom of my question: 1) what I enter into the field in theme options, 2) how its saved into the databases and 3) what is shown on the front end.

Comment: I mean show us real output (generated html source) and the code that execute your "top footer code"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you must prevent WordPress from adding slashes to your content, using something like:

```
update_option('my_option',stripslashes($_POST['my_option']));
```

The other thing is that you want your code to be executed... well I do not know how to do this exactly, but a lot of Plugins provide this functionality, like

[Linkable Title Html and Php Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/linkable-title-html-and-php-widget/)

You should download the Plugin and figure out how it works.

Just take the content of the field from the database now and try to parse it in some way.

Answer (score 2):

Use [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) to unescape the string before evaluating/displaying the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `”` with `''`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this functon of PHP

[PHP: eval();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

you can take the code in textarea save it to options as string and whenever you want to execute it, retrieve from options and pass it to eval.

**Thanks**

**-Shak**

Answer (score 0):

I personally use [Exec-PHP](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exec-php/). It should be quite easy for your clients to use.